# [Rails3]Not able to call a custom mmethod of post controller outside the post controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I defined one of my custom method in PostsController as follows:-

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 ...<<other methods truncated from display >>
  public
    def update_bid_winner (winner_id)
    @post.bid_winner_id = winner_id
    @post.save
  end  
end
```

But when I try to call it from some other controller (BidsController in my case). Where Bid is a nesteded resource of post:-

```
resources :posts do
  resources :bids do
    member do
      get 'offer_bid'
    end
  end
 end
```

I tried to call my custom method as follows from the bids controller :-

```
 def offer_bid
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
   @post.update_bid_winner(@bid.user_id)  <<<<<<<<<< Here goes the call
   @post.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

But I get an error saying that undefined method update_bid_winner :-

```
undefined method `update_bid_winner' for #<Post:0xb68114f4>
```

Help me out. am I doing anything wrong here? If so , please suggest ways to achieve the same !!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Um...you are trying to call the method as if it were part of the model, whereas you've defined it in the controller...

Comment: Yup thats wrong I failed to notice that. But can I define a method in the post model class itself. Will it not violate the MVC frame work and will it not look nasty?? Is there a way to maintain the application logic separately in the controllers itself ??

Comment: MVC does not mean that data layer actions must also be defined in the action. Controllers are for routing and logic that does not have to do with storing data. Models are for storing and retrieving data. In this case, you are storing data: you are updating the bid, so it makes sense to put this in the model.

Comment: Ok Fair enough !!! I'll go with a method in model class itself thanks for all the inputs :)

Comment: I found a just a better and much simpler way to achieve the same from the controller itself. All I have to do is to add the following line :- @post.update_attribute(:bid_winner_id,@bid.user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostsController and Post are two different classes. Notice how @post is a Post object: `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`

Define the method in `app/models/post.rb` instead of `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`.

Comment: Yup that will solve the issue. But is there a workaround so that I want o maintain all my application logic in controllers part of the application itself ???

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because you are calling the method on a `Post` object but you have defined the method in the `PostsController` class. This method must be defined in the Post model file (app/models/post.rb) for it to work as you want.

Generally, methods that update an object should go in that object's respective class.

Comment: Yeah I accept that, But defining a method inside the Post model will actually not follow MVC architecture right ? i mean we need to keep the model, the application logic(controller) and the views separately for a better maintainability right ?

Comment: Not quite sure you understand MVC. The logic for Post objects belongs in the Post model, not the controller. The controller is only there to provide an interface between the models and the views.

Comment: Actually we can update the attribute from the controller itself , All I have to do is use the line "@post.update_attribute(:bid_winner_id,@bid.user_id)" instead of defining and calling a new method in post model. :) And thus I can still maintain the logical operations in the controller itself. Anyways thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Right.  the method you created previously would be a convenience method that would accomplish exactly what you're doing here.  I'd go a step further and do `@post.bid_winner_id = @bid.user_id`.  Even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to achieve my task is use the following line in the controller itself :-

```
@post.update_attribute(:bid_winner_id,@bid.user_id)
```

No need for any new methods in model to update the attribute.
But the inputs provided as other answers really was helpful to enlighten me :). Thanks.